# Merging another person's contributions with minor changes

Tags: git, merge, collaboration

What is a good way to take someone else's contribution and merge it into another branch, but making some minor adjustments in the process? There are no merge difficulties (in fact, a fast-forward would work), but there are some spelling errors and style differences that I would like to adjust.

Obviously, I could merge (fast-forward) and then make the changes and commit again.

I could also do `git merge --no-ff --no-commit` force a true merge, make the changes, and then commit the merge.

There may be other options that I am not aware of.

Which method will be easiest for me and others to look back on and understand what happened?

Comment: When you say 'look back on and understand', do you mean that the adjustments should be visible in your history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try interactive rebasing.

I assume the other person's changes are in `other/feature` and you're merging into master. Do

```
git rebase -i master
```

and mark the commits containing error with `edit` (or just `e`), then use `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue` to edit and loop through the commits.